# How to make a transparent web view in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to display local html file on the web view control. The problem is the background of web view control always in white.

Is there any way to solve my problem?

Comment: no way to do. finally i set the background colour of html file to the same with my view background color

Answer (score 0):

try placing your target control on back of the webview or bring the webview infront 
(Rt Click -> Order -> Bring to Front) and change the opacity of webview.

XAML (Example)

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="88,181,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="88" Width="279" Background="#FFD35A5A"/>
        <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="webview" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="48,49,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="345" Width="319" Opacity="0.5"/>

    </Grid>
```